# How to store string increments as a concatenated String?

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, concatenation

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    String letterArray[] = new String[userInput.length()];


    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++ ){
        letterArray[i] = userInput.substring(i, i+1);
    }

    for(int j = userInput.length()-1; j>=0; j--){
        System.out.print(letterArray[j]);
    }
```

I have stored the users input now I want to reverse what they have inputted and store the reversed form as a String.

I have managed to display the String as a superposition of each letter increment which has been stored in an Array, how do I go about storing the reversed form as a String?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print it reverse you can do that:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = input.nextLine();    
 for(int i=1;i<=userInput.length();i++){
        System.out.print(userInput.charAt(userInput.length()-i));
    }
```

Other than that if you wanto to turn string to array you can use simpler methods like: String[] letterArray = userInput .split("");

If you want to store it as an array or as a new string you can do this:

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
String userInput = input.nextLine();    
Char[] characters=new Char[userInput.length];
 for(int i=1;i<=userInput.length();i++){
       characters[i-1]=userInput.charAt(userInput.length()-i);
        System.out.print(characters[i-1]);

    }
String newString=new String(characters);
```

There are many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the reversed `java.lang.String` in different ways.

The safest would be using the `java.lang.StringBuilder.reverse()` method:

```
System.out.println(new java.lang.StringBuilder("abc").reverse().toString());
```

If you want to learn how to iterate the characters and add them in the way you want, you can use the `StringBuilder`, appending the characters one by one with the `java.lang.StringBuilder.append(char c)` method.

***WARNING: uncommon case ahead.***

There is an special case where you cannot alter the order of the characters, not even reverse them.

It refers to the *surrogate pairs* of UTF-16. Those are pairs of individual characters in the Java `java.lang.String` (say chars c1 and c2) but actually refer to a single unicode character.

If you build an string reversing the chars in that pair (c2 then c1), you would be building an incorrect string.

Update: I have just seen that the documentation of the StringBuider.reverse() method describes this about surrogate pairs explicitly. Read it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()